# Triangle Sides/orthocenter/vertices problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have to prove that:

The sum of the squares of the distances of the vertices
of a triangle from the orthocenter is equal to twelve times the square of the
circumradius diminished by the sum of the squares of the sides of the
triangle. Specifically, denote $A,B,C,H$ be the vertices of a triangle, and the orthocenter respectively. And let $R$ be the circumradius of $\triangle ABC$, prove:

$$AH^2+BH^2+CH^2 = 12R^2 - AB^2 - BC^2 - AC^2$$

Any hints/tips? Kinda lost here.

Answer (score 4):

By Euler's theorem, in any triangle $ABC$ the circumcenter $O$, the orthocenter $H$ and the centroid $G$ are collinear and $HO=3\cdot GO$ holds. In particular, by assuming that $O$ is the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have $H=A+B+C$ and
$$ HA^2+HB^2+HC^2 = \|B+C\|^2+\|A+C\|^2 +\|A+B\|^2 $$
where the [polarization formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) ensures
$$ \|B+C\|^2 = 2\|B\|^2+2\|C\|^2-\|B-C\|^2. $$
Thus the claim is proved, since $\|A\|=\|B\|=\|C\|=R$ and $\|B-C\|=BC$.

Of course $\|X-Y\|$ stands for the Euclidean distance between $X$ and $Y$, such that the polarization formula can be read as "*in a parallelogram, the sum of the squared lengths of the sides equals the sum of the squared lengths of the diagonals*".

[image]

You can also use this diagram, where segments with the same color have equal lengths, and recall that $H$ is the circumcenter of the anticomplementary triangle.

Comment: @DeepSea: *very advanced* since I use norms for denoting distances? Come on, that is ridiculous. Thanks for explaining the downvote, anyway.

Comment: I think it’s a very nice derivation!

Comment: This actually proved to be very helpful! Thank you very much Jack!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to prove instead that $$AH^2+BC^2=4R^2.$$ This can be done by donsidering the parallelogram $AHBX$. Try to prove that $CX$ is the diameter of the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: The following facts ( need proofs to get upvote...) can be used toward the proof:

1)  $r_a^2 + r_b^2+ r_c^2 +r^2 = AH^2 + BH^2 + CH^2 + 4R^2$

2)  $OH^2 = 9R^2 - AB^2 - BC^2 - AC^2$

3)  $r_a + r_b + r_c + r = AH + BH + CH + 2R$

4)  $r_a + r_b + r_c = 4R+r$

You may use these identities in your proof.

Reference:  Coxeter and Greitzer Geometry Revisited by MAA

Comment: I'm basically in the last part of the proof, I've gotten to your 2) equation, but i don't know how to go from there to the one I need to get.

Comment: I get back to this later today,and post a complete "proof" of it... Its 4:20am in the states....

Comment: Haha, I need to understand it for a test today, here it is 6:30 am, but the help is greatly appreciated! (:

Comment: (-1) This is a not a hint towards a viable approach, it is merely a list of statements. Actually you do not need either 1,2,3 or 4 to prove OP's statement. Euler's theorem and the polarization identity are more than enough.