# Possible Textbook Error/Geometry Euler line

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the textbook I found this formula, and after a long time proving it,
[image]

And then it jumps to this...

[image]

My question is, is it correct that $$GH^2\ =\ 4R^2-4(a^2+b^2+c^2)???$$, shouldn't it be $4/9$ instead of just 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triangle Sides/orthocenter/vertices problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551276/triangle-sides-orthocenter-vertices-problem)

Comment: You are correct about the need for "$4/9$". See the ["Distances between centers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line#Distances_between_centers) section of Wikipedia's "Euler Line" entry.

Comment: As Rohan indicates, you've essentially asked for a proof of equation 204 in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551276/triangle-sides-orthocenter-vertices-problem). You should direct people to that question if they want to provide hints.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct, I've edited the question to remove the repetition part. Thanks for the observation!

Comment: It would help a great deal if you defined in your question what all the letters represent and gave a narrative introduction to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the formulas shown above, just do a routine check that $GH^2 = (2OG)^2= 4OG^2= 4\left(\dfrac{OH}{3}\right)^2= \dfrac{4OH^2}{9}= \dfrac{4}{9}\left(9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\right)=4R^2- \dfrac{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{9}$ . So you are right, I think...